# Static images in React Native NPM module

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to create NPM module that includes React Native UI components.
Some of these components might use static images.

Can I distribute the package with the images inside? How can I do that?

As far as I know, most of the UI libraries out there include a native (android/ios) package in addition to the JS package.

Can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I have published a react-native npm module [here](https://github.com/hannigand/react-native-ui-stepper). This only includes a JavaScript file with some static assets. My package does not require any Objective-C, Swift or Java so I do not need to include native related directories.

If you are hosting your project on Github and you want to include an Example project which will allow your Users to download and run easily, you can add this directory to [`.npmignore`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers). Anything listed in that file will be pushed to Github, but it won't be published to `npm`.